# How to lowercase a pandas dataframe string column if it has missing values?

Tags: python, string, pandas, missing-data

The following code does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(['ONE','Two', np.nan],columns=['x']) 
xLower = df["x"].map(lambda x: x.lower())
```

How should I tweak it to get xLower = ['one','two',np.nan] ?
Efficiency is important since the real data frame is huge.

Comment: From v0.25 onwards, I recommend `str.casefold` for more aggressive case folding string comparisons. More information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56084280/4909087).

Answer (score 298, accepted):

use pandas [vectorized string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods); as in the documentation:

> these methods exclude missing/NA values automatically

`.str.lower()` is the very first example there;

```
>>> df['x'].str.lower()
0    one
1    two
2    NaN
Name: x, dtype: object
```

Comment: interestingly this is slower than the map method in the other answer `10000 loops, best of 3: 96.4 µs per loop` versus `10000 loops, best of 3: 125 µs per loop`

Comment: @EdChum that is not surprising with only 3 elements; but it wouldn't be the case with say just 100 elements;

Comment: @behzad.nouri I tried df1['comment'] = df1['comment'].str.lower() but got error KeyError: 'comment' everythime. I checked - I have column named exaclty the same. What can cause an error?

Answer (score 28):

Another possible solution, in case the column has not only strings but numbers too, is to use `astype(str).str.lower()` or `to_string(na_rep='')` because otherwise, given that a number is not a string, when lowered it will return `NaN`, therefore:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(['ONE','Two', np.nan,2],columns=['x']) 
xSecureLower = df['x'].to_string(na_rep='').lower()
xLower = df['x'].str.lower()
```

then we have:

```
>>> xSecureLower
0    one
1    two
2   
3      2
Name: x, dtype: object
```

and not

```
>>> xLower
0    one
1    two
2    NaN
3    NaN
Name: x, dtype: object
```

---

edit:

if you don't want to lose the NaNs, then using map will be better, (from @wojciech-walczak, and @cs95 comment) it will look something like this

```
xSecureLower = df['x'].map(lambda x: x.lower() if isinstance(x,str) else x)
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I forgot about NaNs, I just corrected the answer

Answer (score 13):

## Pandas >= 0.25: Remove Case Distinctions with `str.casefold`

Starting from v0.25, I recommend using the "vectorized" string method [**`str.casefold`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.casefold.html) if you're dealing with unicode data (it works regardless of string or unicodes):

```
s = pd.Series(['lower', 'CAPITALS', np.nan, 'SwApCaSe'])
s.str.casefold()

0       lower
1    capitals
2         NaN
3    swapcase
dtype: object
```

Also see related GitHub issue [GH25405](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25405).

`casefold` lends itself to more aggressive case-folding comparison. It also handles NaNs gracefully (just as `str.lower` does).

#### **But why is this better?**

The difference is seen with unicodes. Taking the example in the [python `str.casefold` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold),

> Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it
> is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string. For example,
> the German lowercase letter `'ß'` is equivalent to `"ss"`. Since it is
> already lowercase, `lower()` would do nothing to `'ß'`; `casefold()`
> converts it to `"ss"`.

Compare the output of `lower` for,

```
s = pd.Series(["der Fluß"])
s.str.lower()

0    der fluß
dtype: object
```

Versus `casefold`,

```
s.str.casefold()

0    der fluss
dtype: object
```

Also see [lower() vs. casefold() in string matching and converting to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745661/python-lower-vs-casefold-in-string-matching-and-converting-to-lowercase).

Answer (score 12):

you can try this one also,

```
df= df.applymap(lambda s:s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
```

Comment: `type(s) == str` should instead be `isinstance(s, str)`

Answer (score 10):

#### Apply lambda function

```
df['original_category'] = df['original_category'].apply(lambda x:x.lower())
```

Answer (score 8):

A possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(['ONE','Two', np.nan],columns=['x']) 
xLower = df["x"].map(lambda x: x if type(x)!=str else x.lower())
print (xLower)
```

And a result:

```
0    one
1    two
2    NaN
Name: x, dtype: object
```

Not sure about the efficiency though.

Comment: Same as the other answer, use `isinstance` when checking the type of an object.

Answer (score 2):

May be using List comprehension

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(['ONE','Two', np.nan],columns=['Name']})
df['Name'] = [str(i).lower() for i in df['Name']] 

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

copy your Dataframe column and simply apply

```
df=data['x']
newdf=df.str.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use apply function,

```
Xlower = df['x'].apply(lambda x: x.upper()).head(10)
```

Comment: As the Efficiency is important for the user `(Efficiency is important since the real data frame is huge.)` and there are a few more replies, please, try to expose which one is the good point of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace missing values and any other datatype with empty string, and lowercase all the strings:

```
df["x"] = df["x"].apply(lambda x: x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else "")
```

Replace missing values and any other datatype other than string with nan, and lowercase all the strings:

```
df["x"] = df["x"].apply(lambda x: x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else np.nan)
```

Keep nan and any other datatype other than string as they are, and lowercase all the strings:

```
df["x"] = df["x"].apply(lambda x: x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Instead of `apply` you can also use `map`

In terms of speed, they are almost the same as `df["x"] = df["x"].str.lower()` and `df["x"] = df["x"].str.lower()`.
But with apply/map you can handle the missing values as you want.

I tested the speed for one million strings. 10% of which are `nan` and the remaining are of length 50.

**Data generation:**
[image: Data generation]

**Speed Comparison:**
[image]