# What is 'in' called in this condition (to find it in documentation by its name)

Tags: python, if-statement, search, conditional-statements

I want to check if some words are in a text file,
but I need to make the search case-insensitive,
so, I need to know how the "in" inside the if condition works, and see its documentation for an option like that.

But I couldn't find it by searching google,
I tried to search using terms like "conditional statements python"
but still couldn't find it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

search_words = ['Day 3','day 3']

with open('test-target.txt','r') as targetFile:
    for search_word in search_words:

        if search_word in targetFile.read():
            print('yes')
        else:
            print('no')

        # put the read cursor again at the begining of the file to prepare it fot next read ^o^
        targetFile.seek(0)
```

the file:

```
Day 3 Lab ......etc
bla bla bla
```

the output:

```
yes
no
```

Comment: That's the same as [`operator.__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.contains)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `casefold()` for case-insensitive search. You don't need to use `seek(0)` as a file pointer, by default, points to beginning of file when you open it. If you are bothered about exhausting the file pointer, read file contents to a variable, and use the variable in loop:

```
with open('test-target.txt','r') as targetFile:
    file_contents = targetFile.read()
    for search_word in search_words:
        if search_word.casefold() in file_contents:
            print('yes')
        else:
            print('no')
```

Comment: thanks, I will also use .lower() to make the file also lower case,,,,,,,,,

    if search_word.casefold() in targetFile.read().lower()

Comment: the file has "Day3" with an upper case "D", so when I used only .casefold() as you said, it gave me "no no" as it searched for "day" and "day" in a file that only had "Day",

Comment: Mixing `casefold()` and `lower()` is a bug, isn't it? It will do the wrong thing in the few cases where it actually matters whether you use one or the other.

Comment: @tripleee, `casefold()` alone should work in scenarios like this. I don't know why OP is getting a 'no'.

Comment: @Omar, Please make sure that you have a space between, like 'Day 3'. From you comment, I read there is no space. In such cases this returns a 'no'.

Comment: I'm not talking about a concrete problem, I am predicting that this code will fail in some scenarios which the OP may or may not have. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745661/python-lower-vs-casefold-in-string-matching-and-converting-to-lowercase

Comment: @Austin, yes I am sure,
anyway, I think a final easy way for this is to use .lower ()
on both of them: if search_word.lower()in targetFile.read().lower()

Comment: @Austin,  regarding the .seek(0)
I need it for the second iteration, to reset the cursor

Answer (score 0):

This is called the "contains" operator, a [membership test operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in). It doesn't really come with options; it simply checks if something is present in something else - but you can "normalize" these "somethings" e.g. by converting both to lower case (or upper case, or [Unicode normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) case [folded](/questions/45745661/python-lower-vs-casefold-in-string-matching-and-converting-to-lowercase) or whatever is suitable for your particular application) before checking for containment.

Seeking back in the file repeatedly is extremely inefficient, though. You want to read the file into memory once:

```
# Normalize once, before looping
search_words = set([x.lower() for x in ['Day 3','day 3']])

with open('test-target.txt','r') as targetFile:
    contents = targetFile.read()
for search_word in search_words:
    if search_word in contents.lower():
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

... or perhaps examine a line at a time:

```
with open('test-target.txt','r') as targetFile:
    for line in targetFile:
        for search_word in search_words:
            if search_word in line.lower():
                print('yes')
                break # maybe?
    else:
        print('no')
```

This will be more robust because you can handle arbitrarily large files, as long as every individual line will fit into memory.

Notice how a `for` loop can have an `else` branch, by the by.

As a usability improvement, the message you print should probably identify which search word was or wasn't found in each iteration.