# Sort the elements of list contains salutation in it?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that contains salutation in it. How can I sort the list on the basis of names (after salutation - Mr., Ms., Mrs.) in pythonic way?

I have tried to split the elements of list on the basis of '.' character  and  sorted the names but could not get salutation with sorted names.

```py
names = ["Mr.usman", "Mrs.obama", "Mr.Albert"]
sorted_list = sorted([i.split('.')[1] for i in names])
```

For e.g `["Mr.usman", "Mrs.obama", "Mr.Albert"]` should be like `["Mr.Albert", "Mrs.obama", "Mr.usman"]`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not sort the manipulated list, you can specify the `key=...` parameter to determine on what to sort, like:

```
sorted_list = sorted(names, key=lambda n: n.split('.', 2)[1].casefold())
```

This yields:

```
>>> sorted(names, key=lambda n: n.split('.', 2)[1].casefold())
['Mr.Albert', 'Mrs.obama', 'Mr.usman']
```

The `.casefold()` is used to do a case-insensitive comparison, which your question sample output suggests. You can remove it if you want case *sensitive* comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
names = ['Mr.Osama', 'Mrs.Usman', 'Mr.Ali', 'Mrs.Ghani']
sortedList = sorted(names, key=lambda elem: elem[3:] if 'Mr.' in elem else elem[4:])
print('Sorted list:', sortedList)
```

Comment: According to the data in the question we have names starting with uppercase and lowercase. I'd do: `sorted(names, key=lambda name:name.lower().split('.')[1])`

Comment: @MalikFaiq in that case sorted(names, key=lambda name:name.lower().split('.')[1]), this would be good solution.

Comment: @OsamaRasheed: please use `casefold()` over `lower()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745661/python-lower-vs-casefold-in-string-matching-and-converting-to-lowercase