# Case insensitive list filter

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to filter a list if a value is in a string.

`filter_object = list(filter(lambda a: f_val in a, f_Results))` works well except that it is case sensitive.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: Related: [lower() vs. casefold() in string matching and converting to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745661/lower-vs-casefold-in-string-matching-and-converting-to-lowercase)

Comment: ```f_Results = ["Abc", "abc", "bac", "Bcc"]```
#
```f_Val = "A"```
#

```Output: ["Abc", "abc", "bac"]```
I came across casefold, but I was using it wrong. ie ```list(filter(lambda a: f_val.casefold() in a, self.f_Results))```

Unmitigated's answer got my expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold).

```
filter_object = list(filter(lambda a: f_val.casefold() in a.casefold(), f_Results))
```

Comment: casefold  is the right answer... I'll reopen if you want - there are some casefold answers in those dupes.