# How can I simplify this code and make it easier to read?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
decision = input("Would you like to try again?(y/n) (or 'Help' for instructions")
if decision != "y" or decision != "n" or decision != "Help:":
    print("This input is not readable! Try again!")
```

I'm working on a program. I just wrote some code, so it's not too long.
This is a different code from what I'm currently working on. But it's the same question:

What's the easiest way to write the if statement in one line? Is there any way I can get all of that in one line?

If this is not enough information let me know.

Comment: That line doesn't even work.  `or` should be `and`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by comparing the input to a list like the following:

```
CORRECT_INPUTS = ["y", "n", "help:"]

if decision.lower() not in CORRECT_INPUTS:
    print("This input is not readable! Try again!")
```

You can extend this list easily and it will compare the input to the lowercase variant, so it's a bit more robust.

Comment: `casefold` is more appropriate `lower` here, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74702121/1358308

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mate!
The List is a good idea! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it to

```
if decision not in ["y", "n", "Help"]:
```

but it's probably a matter of opinion whether three explicit inequality checks is too many.

Comment: thanks for the quick response :)
helped a lot thanks mate!